# SQL Query for one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

Here's my database:

Employee Table:
  `employee_id int(10) NOT NULL,`
  `firstname varchar(50) NOT NULL,`
  `lastname varchar(50) NOT NULL,`
  `username varchar(15) NOT NULL,`
  `password varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'password',`
  `contact_number varchar(13) NOT NULL,`
  `email_address varchar(50) NOT NULL,`
  `position varchar(50) NOT NULL,`
  `teamleader_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL`

Service Table:
  `service_id int(10) NOT NULL,`
  `ticket_id int(10) NOT NULL,`
  `employee_id int(10) NOT NULL,`
  `status varchar(15) NOT NULL,`
  `start_time datetime NOT NULL,`
  `time_in datetime DEFAULT NULL,`
  `time_out datetime DEFAULT NULL,`
  `service_notes varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL`

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM employee AS e 
LEFT JOIN service AS s ON e.employee_id = s.employee_id
WHERE (s.status IS NULL OR s.status = 'Completed') 
AND e.teamleader_id = ?
```

**EDITED:**

I want to select all employees except the ones with *service.status = 'Ongoing'*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want a list of employees that have completed a service (excluding those who have not and only showing one service per employee)

```
SELECT employee.*, COUNT(service.status)
FROM employee, service
WHERE service.employee_id = employee.employee_id
AND ( service.status IS NULL OR service.status = 'Completed' )
AND teamleader_id = 1
GROUP BY employee.employee_id;
```

Or If you do want to list the employees who have not completed any service

```
SELECT employee.*, COUNT(service.status)
FROM employee LEFT JOIN service ON service.employee_id = employee.employee_id
WHERE ( service.status IS NULL OR service.status = 'Completed' )
AND teamleader_id = 1
GROUP BY employee.employee_id;
```

or if you want all except where service.status = 'Ongoing'

```
SELECT employee.*, COUNT(service.status)
FROM employee LEFT JOIN service ON service.employee_id = employee.employee_id
WHERE employee.employee_id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT service.employee_id FROM service WHERE service.status = 'Ongoing')
AND teamleader_id = 1
GROUP BY employee.employee_id;
```

Tested in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb304/5)

```
CREATE TABLE employee ( employee_id INT(9) PRIMARY KEY, teamleader_id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL );
CREATE TABLE service ( id INT(9) PRIMARY KEY, employee_id INT(9) NOT NULL, status VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (1, 1, 'Bob');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (2, 1, 'Alice');
INSERT INTO service VALUES (1, 2, 'Complete');
INSERT INTO service VALUES (2, 2, 'WIP');
INSERT INTO service VALUES (3, 2, 'Ongoing');
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add DISTINCT to your query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.* FROM employee e LEFT JOIN service s ON e.employee_id = s.employee_id
WHERE(s.status is null OR s.status = 'Completed') and teamleader_id = 3
```

it filters duplicated

Comment: what if i want to select all employee except ones with service.status = "Ongoing"